# ADB command doesn't read bash variable and returns empty line

Tags: bash, adb

I'm currently working on a BASH script to get the path of all apps through ADB in order to pull it afterwards. I get an empty line as the result of the last echo.

If I write a package name directly instead if $pkg, il works. Looks like the $pkg variable is not well "digested" by *adb shell pm path*

```
for line in $(adb shell pm list packages -3)
do
    line=$line | tr -d '\r'
    pkg=${line:8}
    path=$(adb shell pm path $pkg | tr -d '\r')
    echo $path
done
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `adb shell pm list packages -3` and what is your action out of it?

Comment: `line=$(echo "$line" | tr -d '\r')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt to strip the carriage return from `line` is incorrect; as a result, `pkg` still ends with a carriage return. You need to write

```
line=$(echo "$line" | tr -d '\r')
```

However, a simpler method is to use parameter expansion instead:

```
line=${line%$'\r'}
```

Further, you shouldn't use a `for` loop to iterate over the output of a command. Use a `while` loop with `read` instead:

```
while IFS= read line; do
    line=${line%$'\r'}
    pkg=${line:8}
    path=$(adb shell pm path "$pkg" | tr -d '\r')
    echo "$path"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I'll keep the while vs. for in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 nested loops - keep the internal one running inside the device and use `adb exec-out` instead of `adb shell`. This way you will not have to worry about extra `\r`

```
for p in $(adb exec-out 'for p in $(pm list packages -3); do pm path ${p:8}; done')
do
  adb pull ${p:8}
done
```